# Getting metabox value?

Tags: metabox, post-meta

I have a custom metabox made using the code from Wordpress Reference:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

```
<?php
/* Define the custom box */

// WP 3.0+
// add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box');

// backwards compatible
add_action('admin_init', 'myplugin_add_custom_box', 1);

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action('save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata');

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'myplugin_sectionid',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
        'post' 
    );
    add_meta_box(
        'myplugin_sectionid',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ), 
        'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
        'page'
    );
}

/* Prints the box content */
function myplugin_inner_custom_box() {

  // Use nonce for verification
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'myplugin_noncename' );

  // The actual fields for data entry
  echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
       _e("Description for this field", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
  echo '</label> ';
  echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="whatever" size="25" />';
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) )
      return $post_id;

  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return $post_id;


  // Check permissions
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
  }

  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

  $mydata = $_POST['myplugin_new_field'];

  // Do something with $mydata 
  // probably using add_post_meta(), update_post_meta(), or 
  // a custom table (see Further Reading section below)

   return $mydata;
}
?>
```

And I'm not sure how to display it's value on each page?

```
<?php 

    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'myplugin_new_field'); 

    var_dump($meta);

?>
```

Gives:

> array(0) {}

In addition, metabox field doesn't update it's value after clicking updating post/or page. That's because input value="whathever" while it should be something like the code above.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

[edit]

Final code that is not updating inputs value:

```
/* Define the custom box */
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'myplugin_add_custom_box');

// backwards compatible
add_action('admin_init', 'myplugin_add_custom_box', 1);

/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action('save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata');

/* Adds a box to the main column on the Post and Page edit screens */
function myplugin_add_custom_box() {
    add_meta_box( 
        'metabox_sidebar_select',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ),
        'myplugin_inner_custom_box',
        'post' 
    );
    add_meta_box(
        'metabox_sidebar_select',
        __( 'My Post Section Title', 'myplugin_textdomain' ), 
        'metabox_sidebar_select',
        'page'
    );
}

/* Prints the box content */
function myplugin_inner_custom_box() {

  // Use nonce for verification
  wp_nonce_field( plugin_basename(__FILE__), 'myplugin_noncename' );

  // The actual fields for data entry
  echo '<label for="myplugin_new_field">';
       _e("Description for this field", 'myplugin_textdomain' );
  echo '</label> ';
  echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'myplugin_new_field',true).'" size="25" />';  
}

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

  // verify this came from the our screen and with proper authorization,
  // because save_post can be triggered at other times

  if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['myplugin_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) ) )
      return $post_id;

  // verify if this is an auto save routine. 
  // If it is our form has not been submitted, so we dont want to do anything
  if ( defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) 
      return $post_id;


  // Check permissions
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) 
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
  }
  else
  {
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;
  }

  // OK, we're authenticated: we need to find and save the data

  $mydata = $_POST['myplugin_new_field'];

  // Do something with $mydata 
  // probably using add_post_meta(), update_post_meta(), or 
  // a custom table (see Further Reading section below)

  global $post;
  update_post_meta($post->ID, myplugin_new_field, $mydata);

   return $mydata;
}
```

Comment: http://voodoopress.com/2011/03/adding-meta-boxes-to-your-post-screen/ I have a writeup here about meta box code if it helps you.  That's for setting it up and then http://voodoopress.com/2011/03/putting-our-meta-box-to-use-in-our-new-link-post-format/  Talk about using the values by echoing get_post_meta

Comment: do you have a function that saves the meta data? usually hook'ed by `save_post` hook? If not then that's your problem you are not saving the meta data

Comment: @Rev. Voodoo, going to check it ASAP. Thank you. @Bainternet as I said in the first post I'm using EXACTLY the code available at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box. In addition I copy&pasted it to the first post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is you answer, in your code where it says:

> // Do something with $mydata  probably using add_post_meta(), update_post_meta(), or 
>      a custom table (see Further Reading section below)

you need to actually insert/update the data to the database
so add something like:

```
global $post;
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'myplugin_new_field', $mydata);
```

and the data will be saved so you could get it using your code:

```
$meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'myplugin_new_field');
```

and the only other change you need is in the function that displays the metabox change:

```
echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="whatever" size="25" />';
```

to

```
echo '<input type="text" id="myplugin_new_field" name="myplugin_new_field" value="'.get_post_meta($post->ID, 'myplugin_new_field',true).'" size="25" />';
```

Update:

To answer your question in the comments:

to save a select list you save it just the save way as a text input and to display the previously selected option in the meta box you just loop over the option and see what was selected and you add "selected" attribute. 
for example :

```
//get last selected value if exists
$selected = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'myplugin_new_select_field',true);
echo '<select name="myplugin_new_select_field">';
$x = 0;
while ($x < 4){
    echo '<option value="'.$x.'"';
    //check if the last value is the same is current value.
    if ($x == $selected)
        echo ' selected="selected"';
    echo '>'.$x.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: @Bainternet, Christ, I'm blind & stupid. I've just copy pasted code and get rid off comments immediately :/ Thank you so much. ANYWAYS the last line doesn't work (input values are not being updated, inputs are always empty). Any idea why?

Comment: @Wordpressor: paste bin your code and i'll tell you.

Comment: @Bainternet, done. Check the first post.

Comment: @Wordpressor: add 'global $post;' to  `myplugin_inner_custom_box()` function, and add ' marks to `update_post_meta($post->ID, 'myplugin_new_field', $mydata);`

Comment: @Bainternet, thank you! By the way, do I have to change anything in the code provided when it comes to select lists? I have a select list with a few options and I'm unable to echo it's value.

Comment: @Wordpressor: i updated my answer.

Comment: @Bainternet, +1, my point was even if I have a '<select name="MyField" /><option value="MyValue" selected="selected"></select>' the array is empty. I'm updating it the same way as text inputs.

Comment: @Bainternet, sorry, my mistake, works like a charm. I was updating metadata for Page Home and checking Page Home2 :/ Thanks once again!

Comment: @Wordpressor: glad you got it.